# Meaning of some parentheses in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I see this:

```
Project.update_all("cost = cost * 3", 
                   "lower(technology) LIKE '%microsoft%'")
```

as an example of `update_all` method in Active Record when I'm following *The Rails 3 Way*, very simple phrase, huh? But I just can't figure out what do parentheses mean in `lower(technology)` here.

So, Could you tell me some possible answers? Because I don't know if there are some different situations we can use parentheses like this.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They call the SQL [`LOWER` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174400.aspx) to lowercase the string.

```
LOWER technology
```

would be a syntax error, because `LOWER` is a function, not a keyword.

Comment: Great! I forgot SQL is not case sensetive, lowercase SQL makes me confused.